# Convex smooth function with a single critical point must be global minimum?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex smooth function such that $f$ has a unique critical point. Is that point necessarily a global minimum? If it isn't, which other hypothesis should I add to the current ones to get this result?

Comment: Please consult this [Wiki - Second partial derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test).

Comment: Smoothness and convexity is sufficient. Any critical point (even if multiple points exist) will be a global minimum.

Comment: Smoothness is not necessary; a critical point of a convex function is globally optimal.

Comment: Convexity and smoothness are sufficient to conclude this. You may even be able to relax the smoothness/critical point criteria a little and still get the result.

Comment: @LinAlg It seems to me that smoothness is necessary. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)), a critical point is "where the function is either not differentiable or the derivative is equal to zero". If $f(x) = x$ for $x < 0$ and $f(x) = 2x$ for $x \geq 0$, $f$ is convex and non-differentiable at $0$, but has no minimizer.